# Method 'Range' of 'object' Global Failed

Tags: excel, vba

This used to work then all of a sudden started getting errors:

> Method 'Range' of 'object' Global Failed

starting at line with:

```
Range("G2.G101").Value = "=E2-B2"
```

What gives?

```
Sub ReadCSV()
Dim symbol, hi, lo, startdate, enddate, hi2, lo2, hi3, lo3, d5hi, d5lo, d10hi, d10lo, d20hi, d20lo, dayrng As Variant
Dim symbpos As Range
Dim MainWkbk, NextWkbk As Workbook
Set MainWkbk = ActiveWorkbook

'symbol = InputBox("Enter symbol")

symbol = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:="f:\downloads\daily_" & symbol & ".csv"
Set NextWkbk = ActiveWorkbook

Range("G1").Value = "Net Ch fr Open"
Range("G2.G101").Value = "=E2-B2"
End Sub
```

Comment: `G2:G101` - a colon, not a period.

Comment: Also, are you trying to put a formula in? If so maybe you want to look into using Formula. Another note, you define workbooks but never use these parent object when you refer to Ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Range("G2.G101").Value = "=E2-B2"` should be `Range(G2:G101).Value`. This is easily visible, if the **macro recorder** is used, just to see how to define the ranges - it works flawlessly there.

Anyway, a few more points:

---

When the variables are defined like this:

```
Dim MainWkbk, NextWkbk As Workbook
```

then the first (`MainWkbk`) is defined as a `Variant` and only the latter (`NextWkbk`) as a workbook. Thus, try to define explicitly - `Dim MainWkbk as Workbook, NextWkbk As Workbook`.

---

It is a good idea to avoid at all costs `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveCell`, etc - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Thus, consider:

```
Set NextWkbk = Workbooks.Open( Filename:="f:\downloads\daily_" & symbol & ".csv")
```

---

Avoiding `Range()` without a `Worksheet`. Instead of:

```
Range("G1").Value = "Net Ch fr Open"
Range("G2:G101").Value = "=E2-B2"
```

consider:

```
With NextWkbk.Worksheets(1)
    .Range("G1").Value = "Net Ch fr Open"
    .Range("G2:G101").Formula = "=E2-B2"
End With
```

because the `.` before the range specifies the range to the first worksheet of the opened workbook.

---

Changing `.Value` to `.Formula` is the last point, as far as `=E2-B2` is a formula and this way it is a bit better, as it improves readability.